# Marking tests as pending in tinytest/Meteor

Tags: meteor, tinytest

Is there something like `xit` of mocha to mark tests as pending in tinytest/meteor?

I tried not passing a function but it raises undefined it's not a function.

I also tried pending, skip. But nothing. :/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not (yet) possible to mark a test as pending or skip the example. The next best thing you can do is comment out the code you want to skip.

Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4421